# Simplifying a complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose $ \frac{\alpha }{\alpha^2+1 } $ is real where $\alpha = a+ib. b\neq0, \alpha\neq \pm i$. Show that $\alpha \overline\alpha=1$.

I know that if the expression is real, then it is equal to it's conjugate, then putting the subsequent equation on one side and simplifying a bit gives : $\alpha(\overline\alpha^2+1)-\overline\alpha(\alpha^2+1)=0$.

But from here I get stuck and can't see where to go next.

Comment: Are $a,b$ real numbers?

Comment: Yeah they are, sorry forgot to add that in.

Comment: Do you mean that $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+1}$ is real?

Comment: $\frac {\alpha}{\alpha+1}=\frav {\alpha*(a+1 -bi)}{(\alpha +1)(a+1-bi)} $

Comment: Yep $ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1} $ is real

Comment: Are you sure ? I think  $\alpha\over \alpha + 1$ cannot be real according to the given conditions.

Comment: Just double checked and the first line is word for word what the question is asking.

Comment: Oh sorry, made a mistake the denominator is supposed to be $\alpha^2+1 $, edited the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\alpha\overline{\alpha}\cdot\overline{\alpha}+\alpha-\overline{\alpha}\cdot\alpha\cdot \alpha-\overline{\alpha}=0$$
$$\iff \alpha\overline{\alpha}(\overline{\alpha}-\alpha)-(\overline\alpha-\alpha)=0$$
$$\iff (\overline{\alpha}-\alpha)(\alpha\overline{\alpha}-1)=0$$
I think you can continue from here.

Comment: Ah thanks that makes sense, but I still don't think I could've gotten that factorization on my own, is there any trick to seeing them?

Comment: @RyanPalmerson: I thought that we might be able to get an expression as $(\text{something})(\alpha\overline{\alpha}-1)$. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If $ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2 \ + \ 1} \ $ is real (plainly, we cannot have $ \ \alpha^2 \ = \ -1 \ $ ), so is  $$ \frac{\alpha^2 \ + \ 1}{\alpha} \ = \ \alpha \ + \ \frac{1}{\alpha} \ = \ \alpha \ + \ \frac{\overline{\alpha}}{| \alpha |^2} \ = \ (a \ + \ bi) \ + \ \frac{a \ - \ bi}{a^2 \ + \ b^2}  \  . $$

This requires that $ \ b \ = \ \frac{ b}{a^2 \ + \ b^2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ + \ b^2 \ = \  |\alpha|^2 \ = \ \alpha \ \overline{\alpha} \ = \ 1 \ \ $ , for $ \ b \ \ne \ 0 \ $ .